# Classification Algorithm in AWS Comprehend for Sentiment Analyis

Tags: amazon-comprehend

Can anyone please tell which classification algorithms are used in AWS Comprehend for Sentiment analysis ?

Don't know if AWS uses Naive Bayes, Random Forest, Boosted trees or any other combinations of classifiers for sentiment analysis.

Thanks for  your time and help.

Comment: Sounds like a secret sauce that no one has tried to reverse engineer?